# Can't create fixtures with dates

Tags: php, symfony, nelmio-alice

I have the following User entity and fixture file, but when I run app/console doctrine:fixtures:load I get the following error and not sure why. If I remove the date fields the fixtures generate fine. What am I missing here? Thanks.

The error: Could not determine how to assign created_at to a AppBundle\Entity\User object

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=16)
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedAt;
```

And my fixture yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
user{1..10}:
    name: <firstName()> <lastName()>
    role: employee
    email: <email()>
    phone: <numberBetween(1555000000, 1555999999)>
    created_at: <datetimeBetween('-5 days', 'now')>
    updated_at: <datetimeBetween('-5 days', 'now')>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but I believe that the naming is not correct, just what the error is saying. I think it should be:

```
createdAt: <datetimeBetween('-5 days', 'now')>
updatedAt: <datetimeBetween('-5 days', 'now')>
```

Comment: You are indeed correct, sir. I was also having a problem with the user_id for a onetomany relationship. I was using the column names in the fixtures.yml, where it should be the entity property names as you mentioned. So also instead of user_id, it should have been userId. Won't make this mistake again :) Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't set timestampable fields manually. In [documentation](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md) and [entity example](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/example/app/Entity/Category.php) there are no setters at all for such fields. So in fixtures you can simply remove `created_at` and `updated_at` (they will be set automatically):

```
ppBundle\Entity\User:
user{1..10}:
    name: <firstName()> <lastName()>
    role: employee
    email: <email()>
    phone: <numberBetween(1555000000, 1555999999)>
```

Comment: I tried that, but it leaves the fields null: 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vdpaywt2gmzc56w/Screenshot%202015-08-08%2018.12.35.png?dl=0

Comment: If I remove the nullable=true annotation I get an SQL error: 

An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (name, role, email, phone, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["Adah Reiche  
  l", "employee", "sstroman@hotmail.com", 1555855562, null, null]:                                                                                                 
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'created_at' cannot be null

Comment: If you have setters for these fields - try to remove them. Also ensure that you have added bundle to `AppKernel` or Gedmo listener to `services.yml`

Comment: The getters an setters are fine, it was missing the listener. https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md#ext-listeners